# Calculate bounding box + buffer for rendering a map tile with mapnik library

Tags: python, coordinate-system, mapnik, utfgrid

Mapnik library has a Projection object (I'm using Python bindings):

```
spherical_mercator = '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over'
p = mapnik.Projection(spherical_mercator)
nw = num2deg(column, row, zoom)     # Upper left corner of the tile
se = num2deg(column+1, row+1, zoom) # Lower-right corner
coords = p.forward(mapnik.Box2d(nw.x, nw.y, se.x, se.y))
```

The tile has 256x256 pixels. I'm supposed to render the tiles using a buffer of 64 pixels (25%) - how do I obtain a Box2d to the selected area enlarged by 25%?

I'm sure the mapnik library has some built-in tool to make this calculation, but I'm unable to find it - documentation seems pretty scarce and I don't know enough about the math involved to figure out from the source code (I'm a programmer, not a geographer).

[update]

Seems like multiplication is overloaded to do just that in Box2d:

```
buffered_coords = coords * 1.5
```

So far, seems like the utfgrid don't match the png image for the same tile (it is offset and out of scale):

[image]

I would expect the following utfgrid to resemble an "ascii art" version of the above tile (Bauru is the red polygon and the actual character is not "#", it is "\u00000").

```
grid({
    "keys" : ["68", "40"],
    "data" : {
        "68" : {
            "NM_MUNICIP" : "Bauru",
            "ID" : 1794.0,
            "CD_GEOCODM" : "3506003"
        },
        "40" : {
            "NM_MUNICIP" : "Arealva",
            "ID" : 1766.0,
            "CD_GEOCODM" : "3503406"
        }
    },
    "grid" : [
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################",
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################",
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################",
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        " ###############################################################",
        "################################################################", 
        "!!##############################################################", 
        "!!!#############################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################",
        "################################################################",
        "################################################################",
        "################################################################",
        "################################################################",
        " ###############################################################", 
        " ###############################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        " ###############################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        " ###############################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        "    ############################################################", 
        "   #############################################################", 
        "################################################################", 
        " ###############################################################"
    ]
});
```

Almost the same code is used to render both artifacts, but I'm still doing something wrong. back to the source.

[update]

The grid on the right is supposed to match the dashed area in the left tile. I can't figure out the kind of distortion involved. Is it mirrored and offset to the left?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code turned out to be OK, the problem was solved by rebuilding mapnik from the [github repository](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik.git).

Lessons learned:

- the utfgrid should always look like an ascii art version of the rendered tile.
- if not, watch out for '\u0000' characters in the utfgrid - since [the spec](https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec) has [provisions that avoid such characters](https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec/blob/master/1.2/utfgrid.md#encoding-ids), there is a high chance you have a **buggy** mapnik library installed.
- I should trust my code.

This is what the correct utfgrid looks like:

```
grid({
    "keys" : ["477", "219", "40", "252", "50", "68", "414"],
    "data" : {
        "50"  : { "NM_MUNICIP" : "Ava\u00ed", "ID" : 1776.0, "CD_GEOCODM" : "3504305" },
        "40"  : { "NM_MUNICIP" : "Arealva", "ID" : 1766.0, "CD_GEOCODM" : "3503406" },
        "219" : { "NM_MUNICIP" : "Iacanga", "ID" : 1945.0, "CD_GEOCODM" : "3519105" },
        "414" : { "NM_MUNICIP" : "Pederneiras", "ID" : 2140.0, "CD_GEOCODM" : "3536703" },
        "68"  : { "NM_MUNICIP" : "Bauru", "ID" : 1794.0, "CD_GEOCODM" : "3506003" },
        "477" : { "NM_MUNICIP" : "Regin\u00f3polis", "ID" : 2203.0, "CD_GEOCODM" : "3542503" },
        "252" : { "NM_MUNICIP" : "Itaju", "ID" : 1978.0, "CD_GEOCODM" : "3522000" } },
    "grid" : [
    "               !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#####$$", 
    "               !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!########$", 
    "                !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!############", 
    "                !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!###############", 
    "                 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!################", 
    "                 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#################", 
    "                 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#################", 
    "                 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!################$", 
    "                  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#################$", 
    "                  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!#################$$", 
    "                   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!###################$$", 
    "                   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!###################$$$", 
    "                  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!###################$$$$", 
    "                  !!!!!!!!!!!##!!!!!!!!!!###################$$$$", 
    "                  !!!!!!!!!!!#####!!!!!!####################$$$$", 
    "                 !!!!!!####!########!!!!#####################$$$", 
    "                 !!!!################!!#########################", 
    "                !!!!############################################", 
    "               !!!!#############################################", 
    "                !!##############################################", 
    "               !!###############################################", 
    "                ################################################", 
    "%                ###############################################", 
    "%%%%%  %%      & ###############################################", 
    "%%%%%%%%%%%&&&&&&###############################################", 
    "%%%%%%%%%%&&&&&&&###############################################", 
    "%%%%%%%%%%&&&&&&&&##############################################", 
    "%%%%%%%%&&&&&&&&&&&#############################################", 
    "%%%%%%%%&&&&&&&&&&&&############################################", 
    "%%%%%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&############################################", 
    "%%%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&###########################################'", 
    "%%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&##########################################''", 
    "%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&#########################################''", 
    "%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&####################################'''''", 
    "%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&#################################''''''", 
    "%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&##############################'''''''", 
    "%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&#############################''''''''", 
    "%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&############################''''''''", 
    "%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&###########################'''''''''", 
    "%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&###########################'''''''''", 
    "%%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&###########################''''''''''", 
    "%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&##########################'''''''''''", 
    "%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&##########################'''''''''''", 
    "%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&#########################''''''''''''", 
    "%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&#######################'''''''''''''", 
    "%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&#####################''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&##################'''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&################''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&##############'''''''''''''''''", 
    "%&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&############''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&###########'''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&##########''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&#########'''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&''''''####''''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''", 
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''"
    ]
});
```